# Error downloading Appium

Tags: android, mobile, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I want to try Katalon-Studio's mobile testing feature.

I followed this tutorial: [https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Mobile+on+Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnDMC.png)

but when I got to the step where I need to download appium, I got the following error:

[Appium_Error_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnDMC.png)

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Obvious is in the error in RED:  Windows SDK version 1.8 was not found. ....

Comment: Have you tried to figure out that Windows SDK version 1.8 is installed?

Comment: My initial thought was to find an alternative and not download sdk 8.1..I have sdk 10 installed and the error says there's a way to configure the project so that it will work with other versions of sdk. The problem is that I don't know how to do that..

Comment: [SOLVED] I downloaded sdk 8.1